# Python - string format - integral part of decimals

Tags: python, string, format

I need to convert a numeric time value into [LRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_%28file_format%29) time format. Here is what I wrote

```
def lrc_time(t):
    seconds = int(t)
    millis = t - seconds
    return '[%02d:%02.2f]' % (seconds / 60, seconds % 60 + millis)
```

The code runs as

```
>>> print lrc_time(20.5)
[00:20.50]
>>> print lrc_time(65.0) # I suppose it to be "[01:05.00]", but
[01:5.00]
```

The problem is,  unlike `%02d`, `%02.2f` won't padding 0 before the integral part when the number is less than 10. In fact it seems just the same as `%.2f`.

So what's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with:

```
"%05.02f" % (4.5623,)
```

So that's saying prefix with zero, the number as a string will have a width of 5 characters (in this case 2 whole number digits, the period, and 2 decimal digits), and 2 decimal point precision.